# Validating whether an admin is logged in or not in OpenCart

Tags: php, validation, opencart

I am currently working on an API to retrieve data in the form of JSON from our database. I've decided to force validation before the retrieval of data.

Because I am using OpenCart, I am offered the function called `isLogged()`.

However, from what I am aware, there are two `isLogged()`:

1. `isLogged()` for the user, which is the admin, under this path:

   `opencart/upload/system/library/user.php`
2. `isLogged()` for the customer, under this path:

   `opencart/upload/system/library/customer.php`

The use of `isLogged()` is (as far as I know right now) dependent on where my Controller is. I am currently developing under `/opencart/upload/catalog/controller/api/order.php`, which by definition is in the `customer` side. So, I cannot use `$this->user->isLogged()`, and instead, must use `$this->customer->isLogged()`, which is against the point of admin validation.

If I try to use `$this->user->isLogged()`, I get the following error:

`PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function isLogged() on a non-object in /vagrant/opencart/upload/catalog/controller/api/order.php`

How do I, without moving my Controller to `admin`, validate whether an admin has logged in or not? Or am I totally wrong in my analysis?

EDIT: Looks like I misunderstood the project requirement. This has nothing to do with OpenCart's user validation, but the user validation from another one of our internal systems.

Comment: If you take a look into the `index.php` files both for frontend and admin side, you'll see that in one only a customer object is registered (frontend) and in the second only a user object is registered (admin). That's why you cannot call `$this->user->isLogged()` on frontend side. What kind of validation do you need to do? Usually frontend shall not know about the presence of admin user and vice versa. What you can do on frontend is direct check for seesion: `isset($this->session->data['user_id'])` should give you the information you need.

Comment: Doing some of my own tests, I discovered that once you log in the front-end, you can use `$this->customer->isLogged()` to check whether they are logged in or not (I just used a simple true/false given the isLogged() condition). I also verified that the functions within `library/customer` all work, given the customer is logged in. However, I am a little confused with the purpose of `session`. Is this object tied to this particular session? I noticed in `checkout/confirm` it's used very often - why and when should `session` be used over `customer->getSomething()`?

Comment: `isset($this->session->data['user_id'])` was supposed **only** to check on frontend whether administrator (backend user) is logged in. If you are within frontend and working with customer only, use it's getters/setters.

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->session->data['isAdminLogin'] = 0;
    if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validate()) { 
        $this->session->data['token'] = md5(mt_rand());
        $this->session->data['isAdminLogin'] = 1;

        if (isset($this->request->post['redirect'])) {

            $this->redirect($this->request->post['redirect'] . '&token=' . $this->session->data['token']);
        } else {

            $this->redirect($this->url->link('common/home', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'));
        }
    }
```

Replace the common/login.php index function code with this.
    Now check adminlogin with this

```
$this->session->data['isAdminLogin']
```

Answer (score 1):

in version 2.XX

use insert this code in /index.php

```
// User
$registry->set('user', new User($registry));
```

and use this code for check login admin

```
    //Checks to see if the logged in user has permission to view or edit a particular admin page.

    $this->user->isLogged();

    //Checks to see if the admin user is logged into their account.

    $this->user->getId();

    //Gets the ID number of the administrator account.

    $this->user->getUserName();
```

Answer (score 1):

Opencart 1.5.x

For example, if you want your page's visitors not to see the language selector only for admin, you will enter /catalog/controller/common/header.php

```
      // Show if logged in as admin
        $this->load->library('user');

        $this->user = new User($this->registry);
```

say after "protected function index () {" and save it.

Then open your template:

/catalog/view/theme/*/template/common/header.tpl

```
<?php echo $language; ?>
```

you are going to replace:

```
<?php  if($this->user->isLogged()){echo $language;} ?>
```

And ready ...

Answer (score 0):

```
// In Version 3.X

// logged in user id

echo (int)$this->user->getId();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// OpenCart 3 (ocStore 3.0.3.7)

$user = new User($this->registry);
$this->registry->set('user', $user);

if ($this->user->isLogged()) {
  // code
}
```